# Error deploying Ethereum contract: The transaction from "Account Name" to undefined couldn't be successfully executed

Tags: contract-deployment, testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, windows

I'm going through the tutorial in Ethereum website and trying to Deploy a contract to TESTNET, copied from the Ethereum page.

When I deploy it, it errors out:

"The transaction from Test Contract Account to undefined couldn't be successfully executed"

Same this happens when I transfer Ethers between my TESTNET accounts.

[image]

Here is the contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract AramCoin {
    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function AramCoin(uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, uint8 decimalUnits, string tokenSymbol) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) 
    {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) 
            throw;           // Check if the sender has enough

        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) 
            throw; // Check for overflows

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient

        /* Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place */
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

    }

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it for me, I already have it enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like me being a newbie causing me a lot of problems. Also the Ethereum documentation that is not clear enough for absolute beginners.

It turns out I had to have the Geth running to make this contract deployment happen.

So i ran this command and had it running and the Contract deployment as well as the Ether transfers went through:

```
Geth --testnet
```